# How to convert Complex Collection to String?

Tags: python-3.x, collections, dataset

Trying to create a very basic script that will display a random string from a set of strings. However, I need it to display as if it were a print function (i.e without brackets or commas). I have tried using a join and encounter an error (unhashable type: list)

```
name = ("Tom")
greeting = {
["Hello", name, "How are you today?"],
["Welcome", name, "How was your day?"],
["Greetings", name, "Shall we play a game?"],
["Well hey there", name, "Whats up?"],
}
print (', '.join(greeting))
```

Any help really would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is greeting supposed to be a dictionary? Or a list to hold your lists?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you were making `greeting` a `dictionary`, rather than
 a `list`.

Heres my fix to your code that works:

```
#allows us to use randint function
from random import randint

name = ("Tom")

#change greeting from a dictionary to a list by replacing { with [
greeting = [
["Hello", name, "How are you today?"],
["Welcome", name, "How was your day?"],
["Greetings", name, "Shall we play a game?"],
["Well hey there", name, "Whats up?"],
]
#assign myGreeting as a random num between 0 and 3
myGreeting = randint(0,len(greeting)-1)

#define out output to be printed to console (its a String)
output = ""

#itterate through our random greeting word by word and
#concatinate to output variable one word at a time
for myWord in greeting[myGreeting]:
        output+=myWord+" "

print (output)
```

**Output:**
[image]

Hope this helps! ~Gunner